# Julia - how to shuffle matrix

Tags: matrix, random, permutation, julia, shuffle

what is best way to shuffle given matrix in Julia (2d-array)?

Function shuffle() does not work.

What I mean is randomly shuffle rows (not all elements).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to shuffle all rows of matrix

```
a = a[shuffle(1:end), :]
```

for those who mean to shuffle a specific row,

```
function shuffle_row(mat, row)
    mat[row,:] = shuffle(mat[row,:])
end
```

Comment: thx for replay, but I mean randomly shuffle all rows, ie given matrix[4x3] then ei first row go last, last row go second, second row go third,..

Comment: great, exactly what I looking for!

Comment: You should write `size(a, 1)` instead of `size(a)[1] `.

Comment: Or, even better: `a[shuffle(1:end), :]`.

Comment: `size(a,1)` is great thanks...Ive always hated how unsleek `size(a)[1]` looks

Comment: In Julia 1.0 one should write `Random.shuffle` instead of `shuffle` or `using Random` before `shuffle`.